# Aframe (how to?) Animate entity or entities with both simultaneous and sequential scaling/rotations/positions

Tags: attributes, jquery-animate, aframe, sequential, simultaneous

This is the menu: 
[image: illustration of multiple plane entities transforming from a pile to a menu]

How do I animate an entity, so that upon an event like a click, it does simultaneous scaling, rotation, positioning, and sequential scaling, rotation, positioning.

```
    <a-curve id="track1">
    <a-curve-point position="4 2 -3"></a-curve-point>
    <a-curve-point position="6 5 -2"></a-curve-point>
    <a-curve-point scale="10 -3 -1"></a-curve-point>

    </a-curve>

    <a-cylinder position="5 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow>
    <a-animation alongpath="curve: #track1" begin="click"></a-animation>
    </a-cylinder>
```

Comment: Hi, can you separate and clarify your multiple questions? There's two questions, and the second one is quite a run-on sentence haha.

Comment: Okay here is the separated and rewritten                                              question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404248/aframe-how-do-i-link-entities-so-the-user-can-link-unlink-entities-and-so-ent

Answer (score 1):

Event-triggered animations:

`<a-entity animation__1="startEvents: someevent" animation__2="startEvents: someevent">`

Then emit:

`el.emit('someevent');`

For sequential, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-timeline-component

Comment: I tried to get this working several times, but I guess I just don’t understand what I’m doing wrong. Can you post an example of it working?

Comment: I also tried to paste the entire example of the animation timeline component into glitch and it’s not working the way its written. Can you link to examples that are actual working pages?

Comment: Also this code shows multiple animations for one entity, something I can already do easily. It does not show how to trigger a group of entities with one event (click) to trigger each of their independent animations.

Comment: We got this working by beginning an animation in each entity with a custom-named event that we emitted in three js. Its basically similar in concept to your answer but our code looks a lot different and is probably less efficient than what you wrote.