# Aframe: How do I link entities, so the user can link/unlink entities, and so entities will animate together, and interact together

Tags: entity, aframe, webvr, webxr

How would I link and unlink multiple entities together so that they can be animated together.

An example is that there is a small pile of entities. When I click on this pile it spreads apart and floats upwards towards the user, so it's not a pile any more but a series of discreet entities each separated by a small distance.

The pile exists of 3 entities A, B, and C

If I click on the entity with id A then they all scale/position/rotate back into a pile.

If I click on entity id B then all entities move to the left. If I click on entity C then C leaves the pile and it's movements are no longer associated with the pile.

There is another pile with entities X, Y and Z

If entity X, Y, or Z is near entity C, then entity C joins the X, Y, Z pile. If the user clicks on entity Z and drags it over to be near entity A or B then entity Z joins pile A & B,

So then if entity A is clicked then A, B and Z will scale, rotate, and position together.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the core question is how to re-parent entities to and from entity containers, assuming it is understood that animating/moving an entity container moves all its children, and how to listen to click events. Here's a container:

```
<a-entity id="groupContainer" animation__position="..." animation__scale="..." animation__rotation="...">
  <a-entity class="child"></a-entity>
  <a-entity class="child"></a-entity>
  <a-entity class="child"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

There isn't a clean way to re-parent the A-Frame entities at the DOM level yet since detaching/re-attaching will remove/reinitialize all components. You can move the entity out with three.js.

```
var someOtherContainer = document.getElementById('someOtherContainer').object3D;
var childToReparent = document.querySelector('#someChildToRemoveFromContainer');
someOtherContainer.add(childToReparent);
```

Comment: Well besides the reparenting question, it’s also about how to define individual or independent simultaneous &or subsequent scaling/rotation/positioning for each entity in the container

So a-entity id=group animation begin=click><a-entity id=A class=child scale=“from V V V; to R R R”, position=from T T T; to N N N, rotation=“from U U U to Q Q Q”><a-entity id=B class=child scale=“from C C C; to D D D”, position=from G G G; to P P P, rotation=“from S S S to A A A”><a-entity id=C class=child scale=“from M M M; to O O O”, position=from T T T; to N N N, rotation=“from U U U to Q Q Q”></animation>

Comment: So my object was to illustrate that 1 click, could cause simultaneous scale/position/rotation for each entity in the group, and each entity would have it’s own scale/position/rotation, independently defined, and each entity could have a path or series of scale/positions and rotations.

Comment: So animate a-entity id=group2
             a-entity id=child1ofgroup2
                  Scale from XYZ to new XYZ
                  Scale from XYZ to new XYZ
Duration
                  Position from XYZ to new XYZ
                  Scale from XYZ to new XYZ
Ease, Duration
                  Rotate from XYZ to new XYZ
                  Scale from XYZ to new XYZ
                  Position from XYZ to new XYZ
             a-entity id=child2ofgroup2
Scale
Position
Duration/Ease
Position
Duration2/ease2
Scale2
Rotate/Position/Scale duration
Scale

Comment: Maybe animation-timeline component?